# amcl package not on ROS Noetic

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recently installed ROS Noetic from [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu) on Ubuntu 20.04, and was planning on using the amcl package for localization applications.

It seems that the amcl package is not located in the shared packages folder that belongs to ROS Noetic, although it says that the latest navigation stack should be on Noetic. Is there a way for me to include the package on this distribution although it natively does not come with it?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355056/amcl-package-not-on-ros-noetic/) by [bags](https://answers.ros.org/users/55826/bags/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you `sudo apt install ros-noetic-amcl`?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1